# Captured count in F#

Tags: f#, capture

I'm a long term C# developer and trying to get a hold on F# and to do this I wanted to do a little project where I need the following:
Is it possible to make a function with the following behavior and how? Note: I know it might be possible with `ref`, but I would like it to be more "pure" functional.

```
let count (x:int) (y:iny): (int -> int * int) = 
    ??

let myCount = count 1

// --------

let myCount, value = myCount 2;; // value is now 3
let myCount, value = myCount 3;; // value is now 6
let myCount, value = myCount 1;; // value is now 7
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible with the *type-signature* you gave (because you return a tuple with two integers there but obviously the first one should again have the same signature as `count 1` itself which is not directly possible - you have to wrap this somehow).

But based on your example I think what your want should be possible:

Here is a version that is slightly different from yours but I think you get the idea:

```
type Counter = { value : int; update : int -> Counter }
let rec counter init =
    { value = init; update = fun upd -> counter (upd+init) }
```

and here is it in action:

```
> let myCounter = counter 1;;

val myCounter : Counter = {value = 1;
                           update = <fun:counter@118>;}

> let myCounter = myCounter.update 2;;

val myCounter : Counter = {value = 3;
                           update = <fun:counter@118>;}

> let myCounter = myCounter.update 3;;

val myCounter : Counter = {value = 6;
                           update = <fun:counter@118>;}

> let myCounter = myCounter.update 1;;

val myCounter : Counter = {value = 7;
                           update = <fun:counter@118>;}
```

close enough for you?

---

of course you can have this way more simple if you give up the pureness (it's indeed rather common in F# to do something like this):

```
let counter init =
    let value = ref init
    fun upd ->
        value := !value + upd
        !value
```

here is your example

```
> let myCounter = counter 1;;
val myCounter : (int -> int)

> myCounter 2;;
val it : int = 3
> myCounter 3;;
val it : int = 6
> myCounter 1;;
val it : int = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention "pure functional" I will mention "state monad"...

And "update" which combines some more: http://tomasp.net/blog/2014/update-monads/

Doing some code example the following requisite is necessary: nugetting the fsharpx.extras into some project made for this code.

```
#r @"..\packages\FSharpx.Extras.1.10.2\lib\40\FSharpx.Extras.dll"

open FSharpx.State
open System

let myCount value = 
 state {
  let! s = getState
  do! putState (s + value)
  return s
 }

let myNewCountWithTotalResult =
 state {
  let! _ = myCount 1
  let! _ = myCount 2
  let! _ = myCount 3
  let! _ = myCount 1
  return ()
 }


printfn "My total with 0 as initial state is: %A" (exec myNewCountWithTotalResult 0)


//Just for the hell of it if you wanna initiate the state with something other than 0
//to get a totally different result
printfn "My total with 4 as initial state is:%A" (exec myNewCountWithTotalResult 4)
```

And yes, Im not sure I do understand this myself.

Also: forget I mentioned "monad" ;-)